# How to create file using ofstream in software's code

Tags: c++, logging, file-io, ofstream

I am working on a software I have a task to make changes in software to add certain feature for which I need to log data .I am trying to create a log file using `ofstream` but I dont know why it is not creating file at any location I tried .I am having code and I am attaching that to existing software process.

```
ofstream k;
k.open("ko.txt",ios::app);
if (!k)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("file not created"));
        return 1;
    }
```

The code above always prints file not created.
I have tried location `%TMP%/orgName/Logs/ko.txt`
I am not able to create the log file

Comment: I found in some answer It said to use that so I used I dont know if it works :(

Comment: Yes I understand that I am asking where can I create without having permission

Comment: I am using windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215937/discussion-between-nurav-and-bruno).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `k.open("ko.txt",ios::app);` does not works that means you do not have the right to create the file in the current directory or you cannot modify the file

Under Windows you can create the file into the directory *Documents* of the current user, and you can get the user home dir using `getenv("USERPROFILE")` or get the user name through `getenv("USERNAME")`, the goal is to make the path `C:\\Users\<usename>\\Documents\\ko.txt` :

```
std::string path = std::string(getenv("USERPROFILE")) + "\\Documents\\ko.txt";
std::ofstream(path.c_str(), ios::app); // .c_str() useless since c++11

if (!k)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("file not created"));
    return 1;
}
```

or

```
std::string path = std::string(":\\Users\\") + getenv("USERNAME") + "\\Documents\\ko.txt";
std::ofstream(path.c_str(), ios::app); // .c_str() useless since c++11

if (!k)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("file not created"));
    return 1;
}
```